Can Constitutional Amendments be Challenged?
The recent Constitutional Amendments in Pakistan brought this question to my mind. Despite so many alarming clauses in the amendments, Govt has also pre-fixed the reaction by the Supreme Court by removing its right of suo moto or even being allowed to take up constitutional matters.
So, now the way it stands, it seems like constitutional amendments can only be challenged in the special constitutional bench. My question is, can these (or any other subsequent) amendments be challenged elsewhere?
Let's suppose, some other day, an amendment comes that these benches also don't have the right to challenge the amendments, will it mean that govt can introduce any amendment they would like, no matter how crazy it is?

Where does the constitutional bench's authority come from? If it comes from the constitution, then a change to the constitution can take it away.

Very few countries permit constitutional amendments to be challenged in any way.

germany
The German constitution ranks constitutional provisions into the core values protected by the so-called Ewigkeitsgarantie (eternity promise, §79(3)), and others which may be changed by a sufficient supermajority of both chambers. The decision if a change affects the core values, or merely clarifies details, is left to the constitutional court. So a constitutional amendment could be found unconstitutional.

Well, it's not any different from the situation here too. I am curious whats the procedure for constitutional court appointments?

@FailedScientist, that could be a separate question if you want a comparative answer, but for Germany the current constitutional requirement is that half are elected by the federal legislature, half by the states' representatives. This happens according to law and rules of procedure of the two houses. There is talk about making the court more "resilient" by putting more of the laws and rules of procedure governing this election into the constitution itself, so they are harder to change.

Generally countries can enact anything they want to as long as the process is proper.  An amendment that ejected everyone named Bob would be fine as long as it was done through the proper methods.  Unless another country wants to enforce outside values through diplomacy or arms, countries can enact whatever they want.
